# Can't install pg gem on Windows

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, windows, postgresql, rubygems

I've got 2 Ruby versions: 1.8.7 and 1.9.2 and PostgreSQL 8.3. I cant install pg gem on any of them. Getting this error:

```
C:/Development/Ruby187/bin/ruby.exe extconf.rb
checking for pg_config... yes
not recorded
checking for libpq-fe.h... no
Can't find the 'libpq-fe.h header
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
details.  You may need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
 --with-opt-dir
 --without-opt-dir
 --with-opt-include
 --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
 --with-opt-lib
 --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
 --with-make-prog
 --without-make-prog
 --srcdir=.
 --curdir
 --ruby=C:/Development/Ruby187/bin/ruby
 --with-pg
 --without-pg
 --with-pg-config
 --without-pg-config
 --with-pg-dir
 --without-pg-dir
 --with-pg-include
 --without-pg-include=${pg-dir}/include
 --with-pg-lib
 --without-pg-lib=${pg-dir}/lib
```

I know it's a common problem, but I haven't found any working solution yet... Oh, I have added C:\Program Files (x86)\PostgreSQL\8.3\bin to my PATH.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

The message you're getting is a clear indication that you lack something for the correct installation of that gem:

> Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
>   necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
>   details.  You may need configuration options.

There is no Windows native version of latest release of pg (0.10.0) released yesterday, but if you install 0.9.0 it should install binaries without issues.

Anyhow, if you want to install the gem, you need a build environment installed. If you're using RubyInstaller, then you need the [DevKit](http://github.com/oneclick/rubyinstaller/wiki/Development-Kit)

Installation of the gem will only require you provide additional options to gem installation (like `--with-pg-dir`)

```
subst X: "C:\Program Files (x86)\PostgreSQL\8.3"
gem install pg -- --with-pg-dir=X:
subst X: /D
```

Comment: I have just installed 0.9.0 without the DevKit and it's working correctly. Thanks a lot Luis!

Comment: Does anyone know if a Windows native version of 0.10.0 will ever become available? I've tried all these tricks with no luck.  BTW: I like the SUBST trick for working around spaces-in-paths problems.

Comment: @jwfearn, I would say you need to ask the gem author about it, can't help you on that :P

Comment: just wanted to add here that this may not work on pg > 0.10.0. I got mine working with devkit and 0.9.0

Comment: It should work now with version 0.10.1, which solves the incorrect locating mechanism of 0.10.0

Comment: For me this only worked for 0.10.0. For 0.10.1 I had to add the `bin` and the `lib` directories to the search path in their 8.3 form. Then it worked without adding the `--with-pg-dir` option.

Comment: I installed the DevKit, updated my path with the routes that Sehad mentioned. and installed successfully the pg 0.9.0

Comment: NOTE: 0.10.x never worked for me but 0.11.x (currently in prerelease) installs OK.  Use `gem install pg --prerelease`.  Or stick with 0.9.x.  As far as I can tell 0.10.x just never worked on Windows.

Comment: This helped me! I didn't get any error during the installation of pg, but after an upgrade to ruby 2.5.7 I kept getting "cannot load such file -- 2.5/pg_ext" when trying to run the server. Reinstalling pg alone didn't fix it, but telling it --with-pg-dir fixed it. THANK YOU!!!

Answer (score 34):

PsAdding for linux users.

I solved this error installing libpq-dev.

Comment: `sudo apt-get install libpq-dev`

Comment: @JakubStrebeyko this worked for me using WSL 20.04LTS and rvm/ruby 2.7.0. Thank you!

Answer (score 12):

I fought this for two days.  I do my rails command line stuff from the excellent unixy like command window provided by msysgit.  I created a postgresql-path.bat file that contained

```
@set PATH=%PATH%;C:\Progra~1\PostgreSQL\8.3\bin
@set PATH=%PATH%;C:\Progra~1\PostgreSQL\8.3\include
@set PATH=%PATH%;C:\Progra~1\PostgreSQL\8.3
```

At the top of the msys.bat file I added

```
CALL postgresql-path.bat
```

As soon as I got the space out of my PATH variable for the postgreSQL directories my problems installing 'pg' went away.  Hope this saves somebody the problems I had.

Answer (score 8):

To fix the problem, I first had to install [DevKit](http://github.com/oneclick/rubyinstaller/wiki/Development-Kit), following their installation instructions.  I had to copy (for safety) and then delete the `operating_system.rb` file into the `\Ruby187\lib\ruby\site_ruby\1.8\rubygems\defaults` folder in order for the installation to run successfully.

Then, I installed the rake-compiler, and rdoc gems:

```
gem install rake-compiler
gem install rdoc
```

(If you have problems with either of them, I'd recommend a liberal use of the --platform=win32 configuration option)

Once those were installed successfully, the final installation of pg itself was:

```
gem install pg --platform=mswin32 --version=0.9.0 -- -- with-pg={Postgres directory short name}\
```

e.g.

```
gem install pg --platform=mswin32 --version=0.9.0 -- -- with-pg=C:\PostgreSQL\
```

The final '' seems to be necessary for the way the installer parses directory strings.  I realize my use of configuration options may be a little more than necessary, but an apparently successful install of version 0.10.0  (when I excluded the --version option) did not actually work.

Comment: Just the "final installation" command `gem install pg --platform=mswin32 --version=0.9.0 -- -- with-pg={Postgres directory short name}\`, combined with the `substr` trick in Luis's answer, was sufficient to get this installed for myself.

Answer (score 5):

**"gem install pg" not working**

Fetching: pg-0.17.0.gem (100%)
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing pg:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

Try this it worked for me and I am pretty sure it will work for you as well::

```
#On Ubuntu
    $ sudo apt-get install postgresql-client libpq5 libpq-dev
    $ sudo gem install pg
```

## This should work with "Bash on Ubuntu on Windows" as well

Answer (score 4):

First install ruby DevKit

On Windows XP and from MSysGIT bash terminal just do the following
based on my installation path

subst X: "D:/Program Files/PostgreSQL/9.0"

gem install pg -- --with-pg=X:

My gem pg-0.10.1 got installed successfully.

Answer (score 3):

This may seem like a no brainer, but I had this same error with a slight twist.  After getting the build to find the headers, it immediately failed and claimed to be unable to find libpq.  I finally deduced that I was trying to build against a 64-bit postgres install with a 32-bit ruby.  Installing the 32-bit postgres resulted in an instant-fix.  Just thought I'd add this in case anyone else with the same error stumbles across this thread.

Answer (score 2):

The message "Can't find the 'libpq-fe.h header" means that installer can't find the header

- Check that your Postgre installation contains development tools ("include" folder). Install postgre development tools in case of absence.
- Check location of pg_config.exe. You need run installation like
  `gem install pg -- --with-pg-config="C:/PROGRA~2/POSTGR~1/8.3/bin/pg_config.exe"`.
  Note that you need to use **short** folder names.

To build a native extension for pg gem you need a ruby DevKit (http://rubyinstaller.org/downloads/)

I meet another problem:

`D:\app1>rake test

(in D:/app1)

rake aborted!

no such file to load -- 1.9/pg_ext`

In this case you need manually copy copy content of
`C:\Ruby\192\lib\ruby\gems\1.9.1\gems\pg-0.10.0\lib\`
to
`C:\Ruby\192\lib\ruby\gems\1.9.1\gems\pg-0.10.0\lib\1.9`

Comment: This solved my Windows installation issues (of pg v0.12.2) - thanks !

Answer (score 1):

Thanks Luis! pg 0.9.0 installed just fine.

For the latest version (0.10.0) you need the devkit and this command "gem install pg -- --with pg-dir=path/to/your/postgresql/dir"

When I leave the additional "--" away, it gets me an error: 
"gem install pg --with-pg-dir=C:/postgresql/9.0"

Comment: yeah, you need "--" to tell rubygems these options are for the extension compilation process

Comment: Even with DevKit and the above command (substituting my own pgsql dir) I get the same error as the OP: `Can't find the 'libpq-fe.h header`.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem.
You most likely have a perl installation in your path before PostgreSQL. The most common perl installation for Windows has an executable name `pg_config` in its bin which causes conflicts.

pg v0.10.0 installs just fine with rubyinstaller + devkit as long as you specify paths without spaces (e.g. C:/PROGRA~) -- otherwise nmake chokes.

Comment: I was able to accomplish this by editing the `Path` environment variable to add `C:\Progra~2\PostgreSQL\8.4` to the end. (~2 corresponding in my case to "Program Files (x86)"). After that, `gem install pg` was able to find `pg_config.exe` without issue and install 0.10.0 correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Windows 7, PostgreSQL 8.4, Ruby 1.9.2:

```
subst X:\ "C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\8.4"

gem install pg -- --with-pg=X:/
```

This installed it successfully.

Comment: But there is problem number two: "in `require': 126: �� ������ ��������� ������.   - C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/pg-0.10.1/lib/1.9/pg_ext.so (LoadError)". I test the loading DLL "pg_ext.so". Other application (Visual Studio C++ writed) loads successfull "pg_ext.so", but Ruby cannot load "pg_ext.so"....

Answer (score 1):

Other easy way, on windows

1. Install postgresql ODBC.
2. Copy libpq.dll from the pgqlODBC lib directory
3. Paste it into PostGreSQL lib directory
4. Run this command (adapt the **PostGreSQL path** in this command, according to yours) :

   ```
   gem install pg -- --with-pg-config="C:\Dev\Databases\PostgreSQL\9.0\bin\pg_config.exe"
   ```

Answer (score 1):

install postgresql per pacman:

```
ridk exec pacman -S mingw-w64-x86_64-postgresql
```

then do

```
bundle install
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem.

The following worked for me. Hope this helps to you.

#### Versions:

- Windows 10 version 10.0.19043.1165.
- PostgreSQL Server 13.
- Ruby DevKit 3.0.2-1 (x64).

Administrator prompt: `C:\Ruby30-x64> subst X: "C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\13\bin"`

Administrator prompt: `C:\Ruby30-x64> gem install pg -- --with-pg-dir=X: --with-pg-include="c:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\13\include" --with-pg-lib="C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\13\lib"`

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem. I wanted to access a postgres database using dbi and had to install Pg.
It took me a day to successfully compile the module with instructions similar to the other posts of this thread. But the second time I had to do it, I found another solution: using ODBC.

1. Install the ODBC driver for postgresql (http://www.postgresql.org/ftp/odbc/versions/)
2. Configure the data source (http://www.xtuple.org/SettingUpPostgresAndOdbc)
3. Install the ruby dbi and odbc gems

   ```
   gem install dbi
   gem install ruby-odbc
   gem install dbd-odbc
   ```
4. Connect to postgres

   ```
   require 'dbi'
   dbh = DBI.connect('dbi:ODBC:DSN_NAME', 'USER', 'PASS')
   ```

This worked for me using ruby 1.9.1 on Windows XP 32 bit.
Also, this doesn't change anything in your code except the `DBI.connect` line, if you were already using DBI.

Answer (score 0):

PostgreSQL 9.0:

```
gem install pg --platform=mswin32 --version=0.9.0 -- '--with-pg="C:\Progra~1\PostgreSQL\"'
```

note the single-tick encapsulation.  (~1 signifies "Program Files", change to ~2 if PostgreSQL is in Program Files (x86) on Win64)

Comment: If you use a specific platform and version you'll need to update `Gemfile` to match for Bundler (`bundle install`) to work.

Answer (score 0):

As of version `0.13.0` of the `pg` gem, you should be able to install it using something like the following:

```
subst X: "C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.0"
gem install pg -- -- with-pg=X:
subst X: /D
```

Then you can successfully run `bundle install` and see the following line in the output:

```
Using pg (0.13.0)
```

instead of the errors.

Answer (score 0):

I got it:

AND THE MAGIC TRICK :

```
is that you do not have this installed -- > postgres-devel
```

so go get it :

```
install postgresql-devel
```

Thats all... than just gem install pg and there it goes.