# unable to install pg gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, installation

I tried using `gem install pg` but it doesn't seem to work.

`gem install pg` gives this error

```
Temporarily enhancing PATH to include DevKit...
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing pg:
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

C:/Ruby/bin/ruby.exe extconf.rb
checking for pg_config... no
No pg_config... trying anyway. If building fails, please try again with
 --with-pg-config=/path/to/pg_config
checking for libpq-fe.h... no
Can't find the 'libpq-fe.h header
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
details.  You may need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
        --with-opt-dir
        --without-opt-dir
        --with-opt-include
        --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
        --with-opt-lib
        --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
        --with-make-prog
        --without-make-prog
        --srcdir=.
        --curdir
        --ruby=C:/Ruby/bin/ruby
        --with-pg
        --without-pg
        --with-pg-dir
        --without-pg-dir
        --with-pg-include
        --without-pg-include=${pg-dir}/include
        --with-pg-lib
        --without-pg-lib=${pg-dir}/lib
        --with-pg-config
        --without-pg-config
        --with-pg_config
        --without-pg_config


Gem files will remain installed in C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/pg-0.10.1 for
inspection.
Results logged to C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/pg-0.10.1/ext/gem_make.out
```

Comment: @NatchiQ broken link?

Comment: in my case the error log said `libpq` was not found, so i installed `sudo apt install postgresql postgresql-contrib libpq-dev pgadmin3 -y`

Comment: Try opening a new terminal tab and trying again. That worked for me. I had just installed psql, and the window I was trying to install the gem in didn't have psql in its path.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Answered here:
[Can't install pg gem on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4335750/cant-install-pg-gem-on-windows)

> There is no Windows native version of
>   latest release of pg (0.10.0) released
>   yesterday, but if you install 0.9.0 it
>   should install binaries without
>   issues.

Answer (score 444):

I had this problem, this worked for me:

Install the postgresql-devel package, this will solve the issue of pg_config missing.

```
sudo apt-get install libpq-dev
```

Comment: Worked for me by `apt-get install libpq-dev`.  Thanks for the hint.

Comment: and for me installing postgresql-server-dev-8.4 on ubuntu LTS 10

Comment: Confirmation, from the [pg gem Wiki homepage](https://bitbucket.org/ged/ruby-pg/wiki/Home): "On Ubuntu, /usr/bin/pg_config is provided by the libpq-dev package."

Comment: postgresql-devel doesn't exist for debian squeeze.  We used postgresql-server-dev-8.4 and that worked.

Comment: Worked for me in openSUSE `zypper in postgresql-devel`. Fixed both the config & the libpq.

Comment: Had the same issue on Fedora 17 this answer solved it (I used yum install postgres-devel).

Comment: @Fivell Late to the game with the answer here, but if you have Homebrew installed, `brew install postgresql` will get you the packages you need.

Comment: @Fivell try `brew install postgresql` on mac

Answer (score 112):

Issue is gem dependency so before installing pg make sure you have installed "libpq-dev"

Ubuntu systems:

> sudo apt-get install libpq-dev

RHEL systems:

> yum install postgresql-devel

Mac:

> brew install postgresql

Comment: The answer for Mac is true. It's just because we haven't installed PostgreSQL on the machine.

Comment: On Centos 7 `yum install postgresql-devel` solved my error related to pg_config for installing the 'pg' .gem. By the way I opted to use the just released PostgreSQL 10

Answer (score 69):

`gem install pg -- --with-pg-config=/usr/pgsql-9.1/bin/pg_config`

Comment: This helped me (on Centos 6.2)

Comment: Worked for me on OS X, but with path to /Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/MacOS/bin/pg_config (I have a standalone Postgres.app)

Comment: `gem install pg -- --with-pg-config=/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/9.4/bin/pg_config ` on yosemite with Postgres App

Comment: Worked. But on Mac, preceding with `env ARCHFLAGS="-arch x86_64"` was a game changer for me.

Comment: Worked for me on OS X 10.11 with psql app 9.6 and gem version 0.18.4 `gem install pg -v '0.18.4' -- --with-pg-config=/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/9.6/bin/pg_config`

Comment: I used `gem install pg -- --with-pg-config=/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/latest/bin/pg_config` for OSX 10.12

Comment: This help me on OS X with no brew support (using postgres installer)

Comment: macOS Monterey M1. Added to .zshrc `export PATH=$PATH:/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/14/bin/` and `gem install pg` worked and could then `bundle install in Rails

Answer (score 46):

@Winfield [said it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4831602/274502):

> The pg gem requires the postgresql client **libraries** to bind against. This error usually means it can't find your Postgres libraries. Either you don't have them installed or you may need to pass the `--with-pg-dir=` to your gem install.

More than that, you only need `--with-pg-config=` to install it.

### On a Mac

If, by any chance, you also installed postgres through the website bundle on mac, it will be on somewhere like `/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/9.3/bin`.

So, either you pass it on the gem install:

```
gem install pg -- --with-pg-config=/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/9.3/bin/pg_config
```

**Or** you [set the PATH properly](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7502061/274502). Since that might be too much, to temporarily set the PATH:

```
export PATH=%PATH:/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/9.3/bin/
```

Comment: for specific version: `gem install pg -v '0.17.1' -- --with-pg-config=/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/9.3/bin/pg_config`

Comment: There is a symlink folder called `latest` inside of the Postgres.app contents folder that is useful in case 9.3 is no longer shipped.


```gem install pg -- --with-pg-config=/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/latest/bin/pg_config```

Answer (score 29):

This worked in my case:

```
sudo apt-get install libpq-dev
```

I used:

- Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS
- Ruby 2.2.2
- Rails 4.2.1

Answer (score 25):

I hadn't postgresql installed, so I just installed it using

```
sudo apt-get install postgresql postgresql-server-dev-9.1
```

on Ubuntu 12.04.

This solved it.

---

Update:

Use the latest version:

```
sudo apt-get install postgresql-9.3 postgresql-server-dev-9.3
```

Comment: Fixed the problem for me but on a mac (with homebrew) I had to run this command: `brew install postgresql`

Answer (score 14):

If you are using **Postgres.app** on Mac, you may resolve this issue once and for all like this:

First `gem uninstall pg`, then edit your `~/.bash_profile` or `~/.zshrc` file or equivalent and add:

```
# PostgreSQL bin path
export PATH=$PATH:/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/9.4/bin
```

Then `bundle install` and `gem install pg` should both work as expected.

Comment: Thanks, it also works using brew installed postgreSQL 
    # PostgreSQL bin path 
    export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/9.5.0/bin/

Comment: Thanks! I switched from brew installed postgres to Postgress.app and had this problem

Answer (score 11):

On macOS (El Capitan). You can simply use: `brew install postgresql`

Comment: Yes! This was all I needed! Install on clean OS X, no Postgres.app

Answer (score 10):

```
$ PATH=$PATH:/Library/PostgreSQL/9.1/bin sudo gem install pg
```

replace the 9.1 for the version installed on your system.

Comment: This helped me on a mac, anyone know what the default path is and how to change it?

Comment: Works on OS X Maveric

Answer (score 4):

- Ubuntu 20.10 (pop!_os)
- Ruby 2.7.2
- Rails 3.1.0
- Postgresql 12

Uninstall and then reinstall `postgresql-client` `libpq5` `libpq-dev`

```sh
sudo apt remove postgresql-client libpq5 libpq-dev
sudo apt install postgresql-client libpq5 libpq-dev
```

Then install the `pg` gem again pointing at `/usr/lib` to find the `pg` library:

```sh
gem install pg  --   --with-pg-lib=/usr/lib
```

Output (what you should see after the previous command):

```
Building native extensions with: '--with-pg-lib=/usr/lib'
This could take a while...
Successfully installed pg-1.2.3
Parsing documentation for pg-1.2.3
Installing ri documentation for pg-1.2.3
Done installing documentation for pg after 1 seconds
1 gem installed
```

Gem should install, then continue with normal `bundle` install or update:

```sh
bundle
bundle install
bundle update
```

Answer (score 3):

The pg gem requires the postgresql client libraries to bind against.  This error usually means it can't find your Postgres libraries.  Either you don't have them installed or you may need to pass the --with-pg-dir= to your gem install.

Answer (score 3):

For Mac Users

```
PATH=$PATH:/Library/PostgreSQL/9.4/bin/ gem install pg
```

This should do the trick

Answer (score 3):

Use with `ARCH` flag.

```
sudo env ARCHFLAGS="-arch x86_64" gem install pg
```

This resolved the same issue you are having.

Answer (score 2):

I'd this issue on Linux Mint (Maya) 13, And I fixed it by Installing postgresql and postgresql-server :

```
apt-get install postgresql-9.1 

sudo apt-get install postgresql-server-dev-9.1
```

Answer (score 2):

Regardless of what OS you are running, look at the logs file of the `"Makefile"` to see what is going on, instead of blindly installing stuff.

In my case, MAC OS, the log file is here:

```
/Users/za/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/extensions/x86_64-darwin-15/2.3.0-static/pg-1.0.0/mkmf.log
```

The logs indicated that the make file could not be created because of the following:

```
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers
```

Inside the mkmf.log, you will see that it could not find required libraries, to finish the build.

```
checking for pg_config... no
Can't find the 'libpq-fe.h header
blah blah
```

After running `"brew install postgresql"`, I can see all required libraries being there:

```
za:myapp za$ cat /Users/za/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/extensions/x86_64-darwin-15/2.3.0-static/pg-1.0.0/mkmf.log | grep yes
find_executable: checking for pg_config... -------------------- yes
find_header: checking for libpq-fe.h... -------------------- yes
find_header: checking for libpq/libpq-fs.h... -------------------- yes
find_header: checking for pg_config_manual.h... -------------------- yes
have_library: checking for PQconnectdb() in -lpq... -------------------- yes
have_func: checking for PQsetSingleRowMode()... -------------------- yes
have_func: checking for PQconninfo()... -------------------- yes
have_func: checking for PQsslAttribute()... -------------------- yes
have_func: checking for PQencryptPasswordConn()... -------------------- yes
have_const: checking for PG_DIAG_TABLE_NAME in libpq-fe.h... -------------------- yes
have_header: checking for unistd.h... -------------------- yes
have_header: checking for inttypes.h... -------------------- yes
checking for C99 variable length arrays... -------------------- yes
```

Answer (score 2):

I've been experiencing this annoying problem with PG for years. I created this gist to help.

The following command always work for me.

```
# Substitute Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/9.5 with appropriate version number
sudo ARCHFLAGS="-arch x86_64" gem install pg -- --with-pg-config=/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/9.5/bin/pg_config
```

gist: https://gist.github.com/sharnie/5588340cf023fb177c8d

Answer (score 1):

I had to do this on CentOS 5.8. Running `bundle install` kept causing issues since I couldn't force it to use a particular PG version.

I can't `yum erase postgresql postgresql-devel` either, because of dependency issues (it would remove php, http etc)

The solution? Mess $PATH temporarily to give preference to the update pgsql instead of the default one:

```
export PATH=/usr/pgsql-9.2/bin:$PATH
bundle install
```

Basically, with the above commands, it will look at `/usr/pgsql-9.2/bin/pg_config` before the one in `/usr/bin/pg_config`

Answer (score 1):

If you are using jruby instead of ruby you will have similar issues when installing the pg gem. Instead you need to install the adaptor:

```
gem 'activerecord-jdbcpostgresql-adapter'
```

Answer (score 1):

On Mac `brew install postgres` THEN `bundle install`

Answer (score 1):

I'm on Linux (Pop_OS) 20.10 and using a version manager (`asdf`) for Ruby (and others) and after trying a million different ways to sort it including *all* of the above

TLDR

```
gem install pg -v '1.2.3' -- --with-pg-config='/home/username/.asdf/installs/postgres/12.6/bin/pg_config'
```

Find the PG install for the right version and point to the `pg_config` in the bin directory

Answer (score 0):

You just go to [here](http://rubygems.org/gems/pg/versions/) to see if your pg version support Win32 platform, then use this command to install:

gem install pg -v 0.14.1 --platform=x86-mingw32

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `asdf` to install `postgres`, just install `pg` gem like this:

```
asdf global postgres <version>
gem install pg
```

Answer (score 0):

Note that this library is called `libpq-devel` on some other Linux distrubitions, like Fedora, RHEL, etc. So it'd be `sudo dnf install libpq-devel` on Fedora.

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/594466/how-to-install-libpq-dev-on-fedora

Answer (score 0):

If you are using MacOS, check the `mkmf.log` to see whether it requires an xcode licence

Run:

```
sudo xcodebuild -license
```

and type `agree` in the prompt.

Plus if you have installed postgres.

```
where pg_config
```

Then

```
gem install pg:1.4.5 -- --with-pg-config='/usr/local/opt/libpq/bin/pg_config'
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

For me `bundle install` was failing (on pg gem). I did:

```
brew install libpq
brew link --force libpq
```

then

```
bundle install
```

successfully installed pg.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I installed postgresql@15 by brew (yes, this is my macbook) like this

```
brew install postgresql@15
brew services start postgresql@15
```

And when I tried `gem install pg` I saw above error. But I was able to successfully install after adding this to my `~/.bashrc`

```
export PATH="/opt/homebrew/opt/postgresql@15/bin:$PATH"
```

I found this line from the `brew info postgresql@15` command