# Uploading to Heroku DB rake:migrate problem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, rake

having a problem with a heroku upload. Quite new to RoR so please excuse the beginners question.

I'm following the Ruby on Rails Tutorial (http://ruby.railstutorial.org), and after the scaffolding, I type heroku rake db:migrate and get the following error:

> rake aborted! Please install the postgresql adapter: `gem install
>   activerecord-postgresql-adapter` (pg is not part of the bundle. Add it
>   to Gemfile.)
>
> Tasks: TOP => db:migrate => db:load_config (See full trace by running
>   task with --trace)

First time around, no problem, but this time I'm getting this error. Any ideas?

Comment: Sounds like you need to run the command `gem install activerecord-postgresql-adapter`.

Comment: @Alex I have indeed tried that, and that pulls up the error ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem 'activerecord-postgresql-adapter' (>= 0) in any repository
ERROR:  Possible alternatives: activerecord-jdbcpostgresql-adapter, activerecord-postgis-adapter, activerecord-jdbcmssql-adapter, activerecord-jdbcmysql-adapter, activerecord-postgresql-cursors

Comment: Have you added `pg` to your Gemfile and run `bundle install`?

Comment: @sscirrus yes, and Using pg (0.11.0) is in there while installing.

Comment: @Alex No, I'm using Rails 3.1.0

Comment: Does [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6410623/heroku-error-when-launch-rails3-1-app-missing-postgres-gem) hold any helpful answers? There are [a few more](http://www.google.co.uk/search?gcx=w&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=pg+is+not+part+of+the+bundle+heroku) related questions

Comment: Well, I seem to have fixed it by adding 'gem pg' to the Gemfile and destroying and creating the heroku account. I got the rake working, which is great :) Unfortunately, it now just sends me to an Error 500 page. Any ideas?

Comment: check your logs, `heroku logs`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not quite the answer Simone, but after more digging, the answer finally came up. I needed to do the following:

In the gemfile, I needed to change gem 'sqlite3' to:

```
group :development, :test do   gem 'sqlite3' end

group :production do   gem 'pg' end
```

and then I needed to **heroku create --stack cedar**.

Thanks for your help everyone regardless, and I hope this helps someone in the future.

Answer (score 2):

By default, a new Rails application is configured to use the SQLite3 database. Heroku doesn't support SQLite3, [you must use PostgreSQL](http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/database).

You have two alternatives:

1. Keep using SQLite3 in development and test, and switch to PostgreSQL in production.
2. Switch to PostgreSQL

Either ways, you need to add the `pg` gem to your Gemfile (assuming you are using Rails 3) and remove `sqlite3`.

```
# Gemfile
gem 'pg'
```

If you want to use Sqlite3 in development and test

```
# Gemfile
group :development, :test do
  gem 'sqlite3'
end

group :production do
  gem 'pg'
end
```

You might also need to change your `database.yml` configuration accordingly.

Comment: Ah, that's what I'd figured. Didn't realise I'd need to remove sqlite3 though! I'll try this later, thank you :)