# PGERROR: ERROR relation "table_name" does not exist (avoiding git commits)

Tags: git, heroku, activeadmin

I have the same issue as this post...

[PGError: ERROR: relation "table_name" does not exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8392899/pgerror-error-relation-table-name-does-not-exist)

My solution was to comment out the related ActiveAdmin files, then run db:migrate.  However, to do this on Heroku, I need to

```
 1) comment out the files related to activeadmin 
 2) Make make a git commit
 3) Push the commit to heroku
 4) Run the migrate
 5) Make another git commit
 6) Push the commit to heroku
```

This seems like a lot of wasted steps and dirties up my git logs.  Is there a better solution that will automatically address this issue without having to do all these steps?

thank you

Comment: You're doing something wrong. I'd suggest reading through the Github tickets labeled "Heroku": https://github.com/gregbell/active_admin/issues?labels=Heroku&page=1&state=closed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was on heroku's side.  They had to delete and update something on the back end.