# Heroku error when running heroku rake db:migrate

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, heroku

When I try to run

```
heroku rake db:migrate
```

I get the following error:

> rake aborted!
>   Please install the postgresql adapter: `gem install activerecord-postgresql-adapter` (pg is not part of the bundle. Add it to Gemfile.)
>   Tasks: TOP => db:migrate => db:load_config
>   (See full trace by running task with --trace)

Here's what my Gemfile looks like:

```
group :production do
  gem 'pg'
end

group :development, :test do
  gem 'turn', '0.8.2', :require => false
  gem 'sqlite3', '1.3.5'
end
```

So I added the 'pg' to the Gemfile but it still complains. I'm a bit in dispair because I don't know what to do next..?

**UPDATE**
The command `heroku run rake db:migrate` leads to the same error.

Here's my Gemfile:

`source 'http://rubygems.org'`

`gem 'rails', '3.1.3'`

`group :production do`
  `gem 'pg', '0.12.0'`
`end`

`group :development, :test do`
  `# Pretty printed test output`
  `gem 'turn', '0.8.2', :require => false`
  `gem 'sqlite3', '1.3.5'`
`end`

`# Bundle edge Rails instead:`
`# gem 'rails',     :git => 'git://github.com/rails/rails.git'`

`# Gems used only for assets and not required`
`# in production environments by default.`
`group :assets do`
  `gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.1.5'`
  `gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.1.1'`
  `gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'`
`end`

`gem 'jquery-rails'`

`# To use ActiveModel has_secure_password`
`# gem 'bcrypt-ruby', '~> 3.0.0'`

`# Use unicorn as the web server`
`# gem 'unicorn'`

`# Deploy with Capistrano`
`# gem 'capistrano'`

`# To use debugger`
`# gem 'ruby-debug19', :require => 'ruby-debug'`

Thank you so much for your help!

**UPDATE 2**

Here's my Gemfile.lock:

> 

```
GEM
  remote: http://rubygems.org/
  specs:
    actionmailer (3.1.3)
      actionpack (= 3.1.3)
      mail (~> 2.3.0)
    actionpack (3.1.3)
      activemodel (= 3.1.3)
      activesupport (= 3.1.3)
      builder (~> 3.0.0)
      erubis (~> 2.7.0)
      i18n (~> 0.6)
      rack (~> 1.3.5)
      rack-cache (~> 1.1)
      rack-mount (~> 0.8.2)
      rack-test (~> 0.6.1)
      sprockets (~> 2.0.3)
    activemodel (3.1.3)
      activesupport (= 3.1.3)
      builder (~> 3.0.0)
      i18n (~> 0.6)
    activerecord (3.1.3)
      activemodel (= 3.1.3)
      activesupport (= 3.1.3)
      arel (~> 2.2.1)
      tzinfo (~> 0.3.29)
    activeresource (3.1.3)
      activemodel (= 3.1.3)
      activesupport (= 3.1.3)
    activesupport (3.1.3)
      multi_json (~> 1.0)
    ansi (1.4.1)
    arel (2.2.1)
    builder (3.0.0)
    coffee-rails (3.1.1)
      coffee-script (>= 2.2.0)
      railties (~> 3.1.0)
    coffee-script (2.2.0)
      coffee-script-source
      execjs
    coffee-script-source (1.1.3)
    erubis (2.7.0)
    execjs (1.2.12)
      multi_json (~> 1.0)
    hike (1.2.1)
    i18n (0.6.0)
    jquery-rails (1.0.19)
      railties (~> 3.0)
      thor (~> 0.14)
    json (1.6.3)
    mail (2.3.0)
      i18n (>= 0.4.0)
      mime-types (~> 1.16)
      treetop (~> 1.4.8)
    mime-types (1.17.2)
    multi_json (1.0.4)
    pg (0.12.0)
      rake-compiler (~> 0.7)
    polyglot (0.3.3)
    rack (1.3.5)
    rack-cache (1.1)
      rack (>= 0.4)
    rack-mount (0.8.3)
      rack (>= 1.0.0)
    rack-ssl (1.3.2)
      rack
    rack-test (0.6.1)
      rack (>= 1.0)
    rails (3.1.3)
      actionmailer (= 3.1.3)
      actionpack (= 3.1.3)
      activerecord (= 3.1.3)
      activeresource (= 3.1.3)
      activesupport (= 3.1.3)
      bundler (~> 1.0)
      railties (= 3.1.3)
    railties (3.1.3)
      actionpack (= 3.1.3)
      activesupport (= 3.1.3)
      rack-ssl (~> 1.3.2)
      rake (>= 0.8.7)
      rdoc (~> 3.4)
      thor (~> 0.14.6)
    rake (0.9.2.2)
    rake-compiler (0.7.9)
      rake
    rdoc (3.12)
      json (~> 1.4)
    sass (3.1.12)
    sass-rails (3.1.5)
      actionpack (~> 3.1.0)
      railties (~> 3.1.0)
      sass (~> 3.1.10)
      tilt (~> 1.3.2)
    sprockets (2.0.3)
      hike (~> 1.2)
      rack (~> 1.0)
      tilt (~> 1.1, != 1.3.0)
    sqlite3 (1.3.5)
    thor (0.14.6)
    tilt (1.3.3)
    treetop (1.4.10)
      polyglot
      polyglot (>= 0.3.1)
    turn (0.8.2)
      ansi (>= 1.2.2)
    tzinfo (0.3.31)
    uglifier (1.2.0)
      execjs (>= 0.3.0)
      multi_json (>= 1.0.2)

PLATFORMS
  ruby

DEPENDENCIES
  coffee-rails (~> 3.1.1)
  jquery-rails
  pg (= 0.12.0)
  rails (= 3.1.3)
  sass-rails (~> 3.1.5)
  sqlite3 (= 1.3.5)
  turn (= 0.8.2)
  uglifier (>= 1.0.3)
```

Comment: Did you run `bundle install --without production` and check in the resulting Gemfile.lock before pushing up again?

Comment: did you check in your gemfile.lock?  I bet that was the issue previously.  Now you probably need to run "bundle install" because for some reason your gemfile.lock is not matching what heroku thinks it should have.

Comment: yeah, I ran that command. But as I am quite new to RoR I am not sure what to watch out for. I have `pg` listed under specs and listet under DEPENDENCIES as well. How can I check the Gemfile.lock for errors? When I type `bundle install` I dont see the line `Using pg (0.12.0)` - this is kind of strange isn't it?

Comment: Looks the same as this one except that you're not doing `heroku create --stack cedar`: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7492636/uploading-to-heroku-db-rakemigrate-problem

Comment: I ran that command but to no avail. I don't know what else to do...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are on Cedar you need to run `heroku run rake db:migrate` although that does not sound like the case. If you are running rails 3 or > you should be using the cedar stack though.

You could also try adding `gem 'pg', "  ~> 0.12.0"` to your gem file and run bundler again (`bundle install`) that should get pg to your Gemfile.lock (look for something like:`pg (0.12.0)`)

If that does not work can tell us your environment and maybe paste the heroku --trace log?

Comment: Thank you. I will try that as soon as I am home. Just one question: What excactly is Cedar?

Comment: I posted my Gemfile to the original post. The command `heroku run rake db:migrate` unfortunately leads to the same error.

Comment: No Problem. Hopefully that will work. Cedar Stack is the heroku Stack that is properly configured for rails 3 or greater. You can read more about it [here](http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails3).

Comment: Do you see `pg (0.12.0)` inside gemfile.lock?

Comment: I posted my Gemfile.lock in the original post. By the way I am running on Ubuntu 10.04

Comment: Hum... You might have to redeploy it and make sure it is on the cedar stack since you are running rails 3.1

Comment: Thank you for your help. I tried everything from the beginning with [this](http://railsapps.github.com/rails-heroku-tutorial.html) tutorial and now it works smoothly. :-)

Answer (score 0):

try adding this to your gemfile

```
gem 'therubyracer'
```

bundle it, and then run all necessary commands.

Comment: No sorry that didn't help I added the line in the gemfile, bundled it and ran again `heroku rake db:migrate` - same error as before. I am running on Ubuntu 10.04 fyi.