# I need help installing PLT Racket, I moved the Racket folder into Applications but I don't know how to use the raco command in the terminal

Tags: racket

To explain, I have OSX and I wanted to install PLT Racket. I don't know how to use the raco command to run .rkt files in the terminal instead of using the Dr. Racket interpreter. I don't really like the DrRacket text editor.

Where do I put the bin, lib, and other folders? I can't seem to access the raco command at all or any of the other commands in the Racket bin.

Comment: If your only issue is w/ the text editor, you can use whatever editor you wish for the source files and still use the interpreter for, well, interpreting.

Comment: I figured I could do that but I wanted to learn how you could use the commands that came with Racket in the terminal.

Comment: I share your slight confusion. Apparently, the Mac OS X package is a DMG even though you are supposed to do a manual install to actually use it (say, have raco available). While I'm able to do a manual install, DMG means (by convention) "don't do that!"

Comment: I added a usability bug report about this: http://bugs.racket-lang.org/query/?cmd=view&pr=13356.

Answer (score 21):

Don't move subcomponents around.  This potentially breaks Racket, which expects the bin directory to be in a certain place relative to its libraries.

Instead: add the Racket bin directory to your PATH.  See [Set environment variables on Mac OS X Lion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7501678/set-environment-variables-on-mac-os-x-lion) or [Setting environment variables in OS X?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/135688/setting-environment-variables-in-os-x) for more details on setting up environment variables in Mac OS X.

For example, I personally have Racket 5.2 under "/Applications/Racket v5.2/".  I have a **~/.profile** with the following contents:

```
mithril:~ dyoo$ cat .profile
## Adding Racket 5.2 to my PATH
export PATH=/Applications/Racket\ v5.2/bin:$PATH
## .. other contents omitted
```

After a re-login, I can see Racket from the Terminal:

```
mithril:~ dyoo$ which racket
/Applications/Racket v5.2/bin/racket
```

I have one additional file, the **~/.MacOSX/environment.plist**, whose contents define more environment variables for graphical programs.  Mine has the following contents:

```
mithril:~ dyoo$ cat .MacOSX/environment.plist
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>MANPATH</key>
    <string>/usr/local/man:/usr/share/man:/usr/local/share/man:/usr/X11/man</string>

    <key>PATH</key>
    <string>/Users/dyoo/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/X11/bin:/Applications/Racket\ v5.2/bin</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Having this file lets me run Racket from graphical programs that don't inherit their environment from the .profile login file.

Comment: Where do you put this .plist and how would you even make one?

Comment: Oh that was my mistake didn't notice the link to environment variables would make sense.

Comment: I tried making this file and then moving into the .MacOSX folder that I created but it still doesn't work on re-login. Is there something I'm doing wrong here? I changed your username to mine, and when I type echo $PATH and echo$MANPATH it responds with the same strings that I set. However when I type in which racket nothing seems to happen and it says the command cannot be found / doesn't exist when I try to use racket example.rkt

Comment: Can you echo $PATH and show it to us?  Also, can you confirm that you've installed Racket in your Applications directory?

Comment: TheVerv: ping!  Have you been able to get this to work, or are you still having problems?

Answer (score 3):

You can just cd into the Racket/bin directory and execute it from there (you might need to specify ./raco if . isn't in your path).  Or you could specify the full path to raco (can't help you w/ that as I don't know where you installed it).

Comment: Thanks, I actually figured it out just a few minutes ago before I read this, I moved it to my bin folder and then created a path. The problem was that every guide I found was for non-bash terminals so when I found out I ended up doing as you said.

Comment: Ooh... don't move it! See Danny's comment. Really, putting it in your bin folder is not the way to go.

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to run a program in a `.rkt` file, you probably want to use the `racket` program instead of `raco`. For example, if you have `hello.rkt` type in `racket hello.rkt`, assuming it's in your path. Raco is mainly a tool for development (like creating executables). See the [intro](http://docs.racket-lang.org/guide/intro.html) section of the Guide for more information on running programs.