# After upgrading eclipse, aptana, pydev, Debugger not working

Tags: eclipse, pydev

I upgraded eclipse from 3.6 to 4.2 and Aptana from 2 to 3 with pydev

Now I cannot get the debugger to work. I get the following errors:

---

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Google\eclipse\plugins\org.python.pydev_2.6.0.2012062121\pysrc\pydevd.py", line 4, in <module>
from pydevd_comm import  CMD_CHANGE_VARIABLE, \
File "C:\Google\eclipse\plugins\org.python.pydev_2.6.0.2012062121\pysrc\pydevd_comm.py", line 78, in <module>
import pydevd_console
File "C:\Google\eclipse\plugins\org.python.pydev_2.6.0.2012062121\pysrc\pydevd_console.py", line 3, in <module>
from code import InteractiveConsole
ImportError: cannot import name InteractiveConsole
```

---

```
!ENTRY org.python.pydev.debug 4 4 2012-07-08 22:09:17.635  
!MESSAGE Unexpected error setting up the debugger  
!STACK 0  
java.net.SocketException: Socket operation on nonsocket: configureBlocking  

_at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.configureBlocking(Native Method)  

_at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketAccept(Unknown Source)  

_at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.accept(Unknown Source)  

_at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.accept(Unknown Source)  

_at java.net.ServerSocket.implAccept(Unknown Source)  

_at java.net.ServerSocket.accept(Unknown Source)  

_at org.python.pydev.debug.model.remote.ListenConnector.run(ListenConnector.java:57)  

_at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're encountering this error, check to make sure you don't have any *other* `code.py` modules in your PYTHONPATH - ie, in your project. For example I was using [web.py](http://webpy.org/) and the tutorial has you create a `code.py` file - renaming this to `main.py`, the debugger was able to import `InteractiveConsole` from the correct module (the one in python27\lib).

Answer (score 1):

I think that the problem is that the import:

```
from code import InteractiveConsole
```

is giving an ImportError. Check if the 'code' module is in your PYTHONPATH (should be at the Python lib: `Python/lib/code.py`)

I.e.: Open a shell in the command line:

```
[07:55:55 X:\]python
Python 2.7.2 (default, Feb 23 2012, 00:24:32) [MSC v.1600 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import code
>>> code.__file__
'c:\\bin\\python-2.7.2\\lib\\code.pyc'
```

If it's really not there, it's a problem in your Python install (should definitely be there).

Comment: Fabio, Thanks for the reply. Tried all your suggestions and everything seems ok, i played with the PYTHONPATH, re-install Python 2.7, everything else is working I can run the applications without any issues, but the Debugger is STILL getting the same error

Comment: Can you do a try..except in "import pydevd_console" (on pydevd_comm.py) and see if it works then?

Comment: Fabio, Yes, that did work! the try..except on "import pydevd_console", I can't thank you enough, I was pulling my hair out. Thank you again.

Comment: Still, that seems really weird... can you do the try..except and do a print('\n'.join(sorted(sys.path))) to see how's your PYTHONPATH at that stage? It's really strange that it doesn't find the 'code' module (it should be there on Python 2 or 3).

Comment: Output: C:\eclipse\plugins\org.python.pydev_2.6.0.2012062121\pysrc
C:\python27
C:\python27\DLLs
C:\python27\lib
C:\python27\lib\lib-tk
C:\python27\lib\plat-win
C:\python27\lib\site-packages
C:\python27\lib\site-packages\PIL
C:\Windows\system32\python27.zip
C:\workspace4\ws2\src

Comment: And do you have a 'code.py' there (under "C:\python27\lib") which has an InteractiveConsole class?

Comment: Humm... it's complaining that it does not find the InteractiveConsole class... Can you do: import code;print(code) at that try..except? My  guess is that you have some other module with the name 'code' which is overriding the default 'code' from the standard library.

Comment: Thank you, Fabio, Adam I looked at this problem again and found a directory that was named "Code" that was creating this issue. Thank you again.