# PyDev debugger suddenly stopped working

Tags: eclipse, pydev

My PyDev debugger suddenly stopped working. When I right click on python code and select Debug As I get the following exception

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\x\tools\eclipseide\3.7prod.win64\eclipse\plugins\org.python.pydev_2.6.0.2012052102\pysrc\pydevd.py", line 4, in <module>
    from pydevd_comm import  CMD_CHANGE_VARIABLE, \
  File "C:\Users\x\tools\eclipseide\3.7prod.win64\eclipse\plugins\org.python.pydev_2.6.0.2012052102\pysrc\pydevd_comm.py", line 78, in <module>
    import pydevd_console
  File "C:\Users\x\tools\eclipseide\3.7prod.win64\eclipse\plugins\org.python.pydev_2.6.0.2012052102\pysrc\pydevd_console.py", line 3, in <module>
    from code import InteractiveConsole
ImportError: cannot import name InteractiveConsole
```

I have configured my python 2.7.1 and am using PyDev 2.6 and importantly when I run the code it works perfectly fine. It does not like my debugging though.

UPDATE: When I click through the pydevd_console.py line above I can see it is importing InteractiveConsole and when I click through that it does take me to the InteractiveConsole class in my 2.7.1 distribution correctly

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After several hours of searching on stackoverflow I saw [After upgrading eclipse, aptana, pydev, Debugger not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11388503/after-upgrading-eclipse-aptana-pydev-debugger-not-working) and it occured to me that at my project root level I have a folder called "code" under which I have all the source code.

Comment: If you have a file called code.py this also happens.

Comment: In the Spyder directory, this worked for me `cd app` and then `python start.py`