# How do I debug with PyDev while running disconnected?

Tags: python, eclipse, debugging, pydev

I frequently run disconnected from the internet on my laptop and started Eclipse with Aptana and PyDev installed and running. The issue is that I get the following error when trying to debug a Python file or when trying to use intellisense:

> Unexpected error setting up the debugger
>
> Socket operation on nonsocket: configureBlocking

My versions are:
Eclipse: 3.5.2 (Java EE IDE for Web Developers)
Aptana: 3.0.3
PyDev: 2.2.1

When I am connected it works fine. How do I get the debugger working even though I am not on the internet?

**EDIT**
It has been proposed that this is a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11388503/after-upgrading-eclipse-aptana-pydev-debugger-not-working), but it is **not the same issue**. The debugger works but only when I am connected to the internet. Is it the Python side of PyDev that is trying to access a socket or is it the Java side of Eclipse?

Comment: possible duplicate of [After upgrading eclipse, aptana, pydev, Debugger not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11388503/after-upgrading-eclipse-aptana-pydev-debugger-not-working)

Comment: @Joran, this one is different. I have no `code.py` modules in there and it does work, but only if I am connected to the internet.

Comment: do you have your network adapter disabled? Im pretty sure its just a local port.  If you have your adapter disabled try and enable it and just be disconnected ... if it is enabled I have no idea :/