# Eclipse and PyDev debugger got errors but the program works well on win 7

Tags: python, eclipse, python-3.x, windows-7, pydev

I am doing debug in Eclipse (4.3.2v20140221-1852) with PyDev on Win 7. 
My python is 3.2.5.

Eclipse Standard/SDK , Version: Kepler Service Release 2

PyDev is  3.5.0.201405201709 from Aptana.

I got error:

```
   Unexpected error setting up the debugger
   Socket operation on nonsocket: configureBlocking
```

This is different from

```
    http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11388503/after-upgrading-eclipse-aptana-pydev-debugger-not-working
```

The errors are different from my errors:

```
   pydev debugger: starting (pid: 16428)
  Could not connect to IP_address: port_num
```

Traceback (most recent call last):

```
   File "F:\my_path\eclipse432\eclipse\plugins\org.python.pydev_3.5.0.201405201709\pysrc\pydevd.py", line 1837, in <module>
    debugger.connect(setup['client'], setup['port'])

   File "F:\my_path\eclipse432\eclipse\plugins\org.python.pydev_3.5.0.201405201709\pysrc\pydevd.py", line 387, in connect
   s = StartClient(host, port)

   File "F:\my_path\eclipse432\eclipse\plugins\org.python.pydev_3.5.0.201405201709\pysrc\pydevd_comm.py", line 416, in StartClient

   s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM);
   File "F:\my_path\python\python325\lib\socket.py", line 94, in __init__
_socket.socket.__init__(self, family, type, proto, fileno)
```

socket.error: [Errno 10022] An invalid argument was supplied

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you do a print on the 'host' and 'port' being used (in File "F:\my_path\eclipse432\eclipse\plugins\org.python.pydev_3.5.0.201405201709\pysrc\pydevd.py", line 387, in connect)

Comment: you just have to update your pydev plugins

Answer (score 1):

I got that error when I switched computer and thought I could simply copy over the folder where I installed python as I did with my eclipse install. Downloading and re-installing using the python installer fixed the problem for me. Apparently, the installer overwrites the python dll in c:\windows\system32 and probably does other stuff.