# Axis 2 can't see JAVA_HOME on my Mac (soapUI and wsdl2java)

Tags: macos, apache-axis, soapui, wsdl2java, java-home

**Question** : Why can Axis 2 not see where Java home is? Have I set it incorrectly?

**Summary** : I'm attempting to use Axis 2 with soapUI to generate Java objects from a wsdl on my Mac. However, I get the error "You must set the JAVA_HOME variable before running Axis2 Script."

If I type `echo $JAVA_HOME` into the command line, it says

> /System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home

I've navigated to the JavaVirtualMachines folder and the jdk is indeed there.

I also have edited ~/.bash_profile to say

> export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home)

Comment: Please post the "Axis 2 script" you are running.

Comment: I'm running it in soapUI, so I havent written a script. However, before the error message, it says this ... command: [sh, -c, ./wsdl2java.sh -uri /var/folders/n-/n-9hW+WVGxiWxpmQkJYeT2kGvMU/-Tmp-/tempdir5351918424628237576.tmp/txttoolsAddressbook_1.wsdl -o /Users/aalexander/Desktop/Soap%20Addessbook%20soapUI%20test p com.connectTxt -d adb -s -g -sn TxttoolsAddressbookServiceService -pn TxttoolsAddressbookServicePort -Ew false -ns2p ]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you launching SoapUI by clicking on an icon? In that case, SoapUI wouldn't necessarily have access to environment variables set in your bash startup scripts.

Take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/135688/setting-environment-variables-in-os-x) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7501678/set-environment-variables-on-mac-os-x-lion) about setting environment variables so that they're accessible to GUI apps. Basically, you may have to modify some system-wide configuration files.

Answer (score 8):

Another solution would be to start SOAP UI from the terminal as your .profile will be already loaded.

open -a /Applications/SoapUI-x.x.x.app/