# Setting up Environment variables in mac

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, environment-variables, apache-axis

**Hello guys,**

**I am trying to build my WS project with ant but I receive the following error:**

> ```
> Admin-2:Project Test$ ant
> Buildfile: /Users/Test/Project/build.xml
>
> init:
>
> pre.compile.test:
>
> BUILD FAILED
> /Users/Test/Project/${env.AXIS2_HOME} does not exist.
>
> Total time: 0 seconds
> ```

**What I have tried:** I have tried the following command and then restarted my machine, but I still receive the same error.

> `export AXIS2_HOME=/users/Test/Desktop/axis2`

**Thanks for the help!**

Comment: possible duplicate of [Set environment variables on Mac OS X Lion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7501678/set-environment-variables-on-mac-os-x-lion)

Answer (score 2):

I think rebooting clears out any environment settings you manually entered with export. You could try that line and then immediately try the build again with that environment setting in place. You can use

```
echo $AXIS2_HOME
```

To verify that the variable took. I also believe the path is case sensitive, so /Users is different than /users. If it works once that variable is in place, you may want to add it to your bash profile so that it loads every time you log on with that particular user.

Comment: You're welcome. I hope you get your project running! Best of luck.

Comment: I am stuck on another issue and posted about it! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15419925/ant-build-file-build-xml If you could help, it would nice. Thanks!

Comment: I checked your question - sorry, that is beyond my knowledge. I haven't worked with the authentication stuff before. I'm sure someone else will have an answer for you though. Take care!