# I can't find libtool command on my MacOSX,10.7.x

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, libtool

I can't find libtool command.I tried to run $man libtool,Terminal returned "No manual entry for libtool"
So I tried to download libtool from GNU site and install it... Still I can't find the libtool command.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: you also have to make sure /usr/bin as well as /usr/local/bin (for homebrew) is in your $PATH

Comment: @Chris:How to achieve that?

Comment: if you run your application from the commandline, you can check what is inside the PATH variable, by calling "echo $PATH", you can probably find more information about how to setup your environment properly here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7501678/set-environment-variables-on-mac-os-x-lion

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you actually successfully compiled libtool, did you do the following:

```
./configure --prefix=/usr
make
make install
```

I otherwise can highly recommend using homebrew to install any standard library that did not come with Mac OS X: http://brew.sh

After setting it up, you could install libtool by typing:

```
brew install libtool
```

Comment: `brew install libtool` installs `glibtools` on mac . building projects which use native libtools may throw a make error sometimes !

Answer (score 3):

maybe this work
I find my libtool within the following path
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/libtool

Comment: @word:Yea.I could able to locate most of commands at "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin" which were missing at "/usr/bin".