# How to set the ANDROID_HOME environment variable?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, maven, environment-variables

For Maven to work properly I need to set the ANDROID_HOME variable to point to my SDK directory. I suppose the directory I need to set it to is "/Users/kramer65/dev/adt-bundle-mac-x86_64-20130917/sdk".

But my question: how do I set this variable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Set environment variables on Mac OS X Lion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7501678/set-environment-variables-on-mac-os-x-lion)

Here is explained how to set environmental variables in MacOS.