# Can't create new foundation project

Tags: ruby, bash, rubygems, zurb-foundation

so I'm following this tutorial here:
http://foundation.zurb.com/learn/video-started-with-foundation.html

I `cd` into my project folder, ruby is installed, I install bower, install foundation

`gem install foundation`

However I can't create a new foundation project.

[According to the site](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/sass.html), the command is just `foundation new PROJECT_NAME`

I am currently getting the error: *bash: foundation: command not found*

[image]

Here is my foundation install path

```
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/foundation-1.0.1/.gitignore
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/foundation-1.0.1/Gemfile
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/foundation-1.0.1/LICENSE.txt
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/foundation-1.0.1/README.md
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/foundation-1.0.1/Rakefile
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/foundation-1.0.1/bin/foundation
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/foundation-1.0.1/foundation-cli.gemspec
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/foundation-1.0.1/lib/foundation/cli.rb
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/foundation-1.0.1/lib/foundation/cli/generator.rb
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/foundation-1.0.1/lib/foundation/cli/version.rb
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/foundation-1.0.1/test/Gemfile
/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.0.0-p195/bin/foundation
Successfully installed foundation-1.0.1
Parsing documentation for foundation-1.0.1
Parsing sources...
100% [ 3/ 3]  lib/foundation/cli/version.rb
1 gem installed
Leons-MacBook-Pro:websites leongaban$
```

-

```
/user/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/foundation-1.0.1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First try to find where  foundation is installed:

```
updatedb && locate foundation
```

if foundation path is not in your PATH variable, add it:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/path/to/your/foundation
```

also in installation process use `-V` option to see where the foundation is installed

Comment: oh cool thanks, did not know about that `-V` during install. I pasted the path above. What should I do next to be able to create foundation projects? `export PATH=$PATH:/user/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/foundation-1.0.1
`

Comment: invoke `/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.0.0-p195/bin/foundation` or add it to your path: `export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.0.0-p195/bin` and run `foundation new YOUR_PROJECT`

Comment: *SWEET thanks!* :D I would have had NO idea to create and export a PATH variable.. just got my foundation project created :)

Comment: @LeonGaban just one note: add above command into your ~/.bashrc file so you will have it every time you start new session

Comment: to do that, I go to my root user dir, vim .bashrc right? I just did that and it opened up a blank file?

Comment: actually the file is `~/.bash_profile` see [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7501678/set-environment-variables-on-mac-os-x-lion)

Comment: This answer no longer works :( will be posting a new question again soon