# Using anaconda/ipython in terminal

Tags: python, ipython, anaconda

I recently installed ipython by installing anaconda. However, whenever I type in conda, I get `command not found: conda`. I have to type in `export PATH=~/anaconda/bin:$PATH` before I can use conda or ipython.

I know there's probably a way to do this by editing ~./bashrc or something. Could someone help me with this? Thanks!

Comment: Related. This question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7501678/set-environment-variables-on-mac-os-x-lion

Comment: The Anaconda installer should have done this for you when you installed it, unless you explicitly told it not to.