# Changing Python path under Mac OS for applications other than the terminal

Tags: python, macos, terminal, finder, pythonpath

I have a Python script that I'd like to be able to run with a minimum of fuss from the Finder or Quicksilver. Unfortunately, any way of running the script that doesn't use the terminal can't find my libraries.

For example, running

```
do shell script "~/anaconda/bin/python -c 'import sys; print len(sys.path)'"
```

from Applescript gives a value of 13, but running

```
~/anaconda/bin/python -c 'import sys; print len(sys.path)'
```

from the terminal gives 15. This makes me think that `.bash_profile` may not be the best place to modify my Python path. Is there a way to make changes to the Python path that will affect both the terminal and everything else? If so, is that the preferred method of modifying the Python path?

Here's some version info for my setup:

```
Python 2.7.6 |Anaconda 1.8.0 (x86_64)| (default, Nov 11 2013, 10:49:09) 
[GCC 4.0.1 (Apple Inc. build 5493)] on darwin
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the environment variable [PYTHONPATH](http://docs.python.org/2/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONPATH). Now, I'm not a Mac user, but from some research I'd say you have to modify `~/.MacOSX/environment.plist` as described here: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPRuntimeConfig/Articles/EnvironmentVars.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002093-BCIJIJBH

Comment: Youch! Setting Mac environment variables appears to be a difficult and ever-changing process. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7501678/set-environment-variables-on-mac-os-x-lion) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/135688/setting-environment-variables-in-os-x). It seems like what I need is going to be yet a different thing so I started [my own question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21972753/system-environment-is-different-between-applescript-editor-and-running-my-script).