# Setting environmental variable in MAC for protege plugin development

Tags: macos

How to permanently set PROTEGE_HOME environment variable in Mac OS (10.9.5). For protege plugin development from eclipse.

Thanks,
Sai

Comment: Duplicate: [Set environment variables on Mac OS X Lion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7501678/set-environment-variables-on-mac-os-x-lion) (accepted answer includes update for OS X 10.9 Mavericks).

Answer (score 0):

In Terminal type the following:

```
$ sudo launchctl setenv PROTEGE_HOME true
Password:<you have to insert your password here>
$ sudo launchctl getenv PROTEGE_HOME
true
```

You could unset the variable with the command:

```
$ sudo launchctl unsetenv PROTEGE_HOME
```