# Why R is calling system python instead of default python in user path

Tags: python, r

I use a self installed python distribution in my home directory. Everything woks well. However, R behaves quite strange,`system('python -V')` returns the version of python installed on `/usr/bin/python`. If I execuete `Sys.which('python')`, the system python path is returned. How can I set R to execute `python` in the home directory instead of system wide python. I do not want to add absolute path to the code, since the code is running on different machine.

Comment: Why just not call `system('/correct_path/python -V')`?

Comment: Have you added your self-installed Python's directory to the PATH?

Comment: @Marius Yes, the python is executed correctly from Terminal.

Comment: @romantsegelskyi The code is used on Mac and Windows at the same time, I do not like to maintain two version of the code in the program.

Comment: It's a long shot, but maybe try `system2` instead of `system`

Comment: @romantsegelskyi already tried, same result.

Comment: Do you have this problem on both OSes? Does the correct path appear in `Sys.getenv('PATH')`?

Comment: @jbaums actually yes. Slightly different, I have only one python under Windows, but has some odd behaviors too. [Check this out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27097787/anaconda-mkl-not-licensed-properly-when-called-from-r). Maybe they are caused by the same reason.

Comment: Sorry - edited my comment a bit late. Does the correct Python path exist in `Sys.getenv('PATH')`? It seems that on OSX, environment variables in `.profile` [aren't inherited by GUI apps](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/communities/public/questions/200629578-system-call-from-RStudio-does-not-find-path-same-command-from-commandline-R-works-fine-). Are you using R terminal, or e.g. RStudio (and is the behaviour consistent across the two?)?

Comment: @jbaums Yes, I am using RStudio on OSX. You are right, the command works in R terminal, but not RStudio. It seems I have to start RStudio from commandline to avoid this problem.

Comment: In that case, maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7502061/489704) will help.

Comment: also try: `utils::install.packages` instead of just `install.packages` RStudio has some weird overwrites that can be avoided this way....