# Anaconda mkl not licensed properly when called from R

Tags: python, r, anaconda, intel-mkl

I installed Anaconda on my machine, in console, the mkl package is licensed correctly, but when execute from R by `system` command, the mkl is not licensed correctly. As shown in below:

In R:

```
> system('python -V')
Python 2.7.7 :: Anaconda 2.0.1 (32-bit)

> system('python -c "import mkl"')
Vendor:  Continuum Analytics, Inc.
Package: mkl
Message: trial mode expires in 29 days
```

In console calling `ipython`

```
Python 2.7.7 |Anaconda 2.0.1 (32-bit)| (default, Jun 11 2014, 10:41:43) [MSC v.1
500 32 bit (Intel)]
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

IPython 2.1.0 -- An enhanced Interactive Python.
Anaconda is brought to you by Continuum Analytics.
Please check out: http://continuum.io/thanks and https://binstar.org
?         -> Introduction and overview of IPython's features.
%quickref -> Quick reference.
help      -> Python's own help system.
object?   -> Details about 'object', use 'object??' for extra details.

In [1]: import mkl

In [2]: mkl.get_version_string()
Out[2]: u'Intel(R) Math Kernel Library Version 11.1.1 Product Build 20131010 for
 32-bit applications'
```

Comment: Are you sure the `system` command is calling the same `python` executable?

Comment: @asmeurer Yes, I only have one python installed.