# jekyll installed but the terminal diplays : command not found

Tags: rubygems, jekyll

I'm trying to install Jekyll on Mac OS X. When I run the command `gem install jekyll` the terminal displays :

```
thegentletrainer1$ gem install jekyll
Fetching: jekyll-2.5.2.gem (100%)
Successfully installed jekyll-2.5.2
Parsing documentation for jekyll-2.5.2
Installing ri documentation for jekyll-2.5.2
Done installing documentation for jekyll after 2 seconds
1 gem installed
```

but when I try to create new project using : `jekyll new site` I get :

```
-bash: jekyll: command not found
```

Any advice ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok , well I don't what was exactly the reason , but I had to uninstall ruby and reinstall it from scratch as well as python .. I just followed this tutorial and it could help me

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EtqZVTIro_c

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the location which the Gem executables are being installed to is not in your path.

To confirm, you can view the Gem configuration by running (in the Terminal) `gem environment`. The line you are interested in is "EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY".

You can view the current path by running `echo $PATH`.

If the result of the first command is not in the second (as I suspect), edit your .profile file to add the executable directory. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7502128/230449) provides some more information on how to do this.

Comment: Well answer your own question so the next person with the issue can learn from it.