# How to set JDK environment variable on MAC

Tags: java-7

I am new on MAC. I've installed dk-7u60 and now I have to set it's variable path as we do on windows.But  I could not understand how to do this. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

Sinche OS X is built under Unix, you can use

`~/.bash_profile`

Also recommend you after posting make a little research look at this question

[Similar issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7501678/set-environment-variables-on-mac-os-x-lion)