# Javac version doesn't update

Tags: java, macos, javac

I'm trying to compile a jar on my mac using 1.8 as a target release, but javac fails with the message "invalid target release".

When I run `javac -version` it gives me "javac 1.6.0_29".

I have the 1.8 jdk installed under "/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_40.jdk", but even when I run `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_40.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/javac -version` it gives me "javac 1.6.0_29".

Sym linking the CurrentJDK folder in "/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/" to the jdk folder in Library didn't change anything. Neither did sym linking the javac inside /usr/bin to the javac in my jdk folder.

Any ideas how to get javac to use my 1.8 version ?

Thank you very much!

**UPDATE**

My path variables output the following:

`echo $PATH`
/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:/opt/X11/bin:/usr/local/git/bin:/Developer/Tools/Panda3D

`echo $JAVA_HOME` (since I set it already in order to get javac to work)
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_40.jdk/Contents/Home/

Preprending /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_40.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/ to the $PATH variable didn't change the output for javac -version either.

**UPDATE 2**

Other question: What does javac do? Is it executing its code directly or depending on other binaries in the system? If so the link for them could be broken. Otherwise I wonder why executing the binary inside my 1.8 jdk folder gives me the version 1.6.

Comment: What happens if you type `which javac`? What does your PATH look like?

Comment: which javac points to `/usr/bin/javac`, echo $PATH results in `/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:/opt/X11/bin:/usr/local/git/bin:/Developer/Tools/Panda3D`

Comment: Download the JDK again. The binary can't be wrong when it says 1.6

Comment: That's what confuses me the most. But I downloaded the jdk from http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html, so it should be fine I assume.

I just removed the jdk folder, downloaded the dmg and ran it again. Still, executing the javac from the folder directly with the parameter -version gives me 1.6.0_29..

Answer (score 4):

The proper Debian/Ubuntu way to configure which javac is pointed to by `/usr/bin/javac` is to use the `update-alternatives` command. You can do it interactively, and select from a list of available options:

```
sudo update-alternatives --config javac
```

and for java:

```
sudo update-alternatives --config java
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to what @Zakaria said, this command will show you all Java packages installed on the system, e.g.:

```
$ update-java-alternatives -l

java-1.7.0-openjdk-amd64 1071 /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-amd64
java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64 1069 /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64
```

This one an overview of the Java tools and which version will be used, e.g.:

```
$ update-alternatives --get-selections | grep java
...
java     manual   /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java
javac    auto     /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/bin/javac
javadoc  auto     /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/bin/javadoc
...
```

As shown above here `java` would run from version 8, and `javac` from version 7.

If you want to update selections for all of the Java tools in one go try the following replacing the package name with one of your choice:

```
$ sudo update-java-alternatives -s java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64
```

Verify that this has actually worked. If it didn't or partially did you have to resort to a semi-manual way, for example:

```
$ for i in $(update-alternatives --get-selections | grep java | awk '{system("basename "$3)}'); do sudo update-alternatives --config $i; done
```

Comment: That's very handy script, because update-java-alternatives invocation worked only for java and for javac, jar etc it changed to default configuration that was wrong java version. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

where does the ***/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/CurrentJDK*** link refer to?

Make sure it refers to the proper JDK

***/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk{major}.{minor}.{macro[_update]}.jdk***

Comment: the CurrentJDK links to `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_40.jdk/Contents/`..

Answer (score 0):

Please check that both JAVA_HOME and PATH environment variables point to the 1.8 folder and have no link to the 1.6 java folder, especially the PATH.

Check:

echo %PATH%

Set:

export PATH="java8 folder":$PATH

or check this page: [Set environment variables on Mac OS X Lion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7501678/set-environment-variables-on-mac-os-x-lion)

Comment: Hey Miklos,
I set the JAVA_HOME to the 1.8 jdk explicitly already. Therefore echo $JAVA_HOME outputs `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_40.jdk/Contents/Home/`. Still javac -version results in 1.6.0_29. I prepended "/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_40.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/" to my $PATH variable as well, still same result. Please see the update for the my path variables.

Answer (score 0):

### Do the following steps

- In the Windows Search bar, type "environment".
- In your environment variables (account), create a variable called JAVA_HOME. Set it to C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_65 (or wherever your JDK is).
- In your system environment variables, edit PATH. Put this at the beginning of the PATH value: %JAVA_HOME%\bin;
- Press OK.
- Exit any command windows you are in.
- Launch a command window. Type javac -version. 
  you should get this response: javac 1.8.0_65