# How to set up an environment variable with mac os x thats accessible from apache tomcat server

Tags: macos, apache, tomcat

Having a hard time trying to set it up. Tried solutions through some of the other questions but same results. How can I be able to set up the tomcat server?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Set environment variables on Mac OS X Lion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7501678/set-environment-variables-on-mac-os-x-lion)

Comment: Sorry I should've been more specific. I am using the Yosemite edition. I found the answer on this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385934/setting-environment-variables-via-launchd-conf-no-longer-works-in-os-x-yosemite