# -bash: set: -g: invalid option when I setting GOPATH

Tags: go, terminal

When I set my `GOPATH` use:

```
set -gx GOPATH /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.8.1
```

I get this issue:

> -bash: set: -g: invalid option
>   set: usage: set [--abefhkmnptuvxBCHP] [-o option] [arg ...]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **bash** command `set` doesn't support the `g` option. Also this command is not used for setting environment variables all together - your snippet is probably intended for a different shell (fishshell?).

In `bash`, use `export` as suggested:

```
export GOPATH /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.8.1
```

However, you should understand what you are doing and how to configure your environment on MacOS (guessing from 'Cellar' in your path).

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7501678/set-environment-variables-on-mac-os-x-lion) might be a good starting point.

Answer (score -1):

You should set GOROOT environment variable instead of GOPATH.

GOROOT should reference a folder (where go is installed), not the go executable itself

```
export GOROOT=/usr/local/go
export PATH=$PATH:$GOROOT/bin
```

GOPATH should reference a folder under which you will find src, pkg and bin. (it should not reference directly the src folder):
See "How to Write Go Code - Workspace"

Regarding the GOPATH:

- try and set it in your ~/.bashrc (using export).
- check that your current shell is a bash (and not another one like fish)
- check the output of go env.

Comment: Sorry, but this answer is wrong. See [this](https://dave.cheney.net/2013/06/14/you-dont-need-to-set-goroot-really).

Comment: @Carpetsmoker Correct.We dont need to set GOROOT explicitly but in question qg_java is trying to set path which is pointing to root directory of good.

Comment: That's probably because he's confused and isn't sure what he's doing :-)

Comment: Yes that is the reason if he is trying to set that path then he should use GOROOT