# How to set TERM=xterm by default in bash terminal in VS Code on Windows

Tags: bash, visual-studio-code

I have linked my bash terminal into my VS Code interface. However everytime I start VS Code I need to set TERM=xterm in order to have my backspace key work properly.

Where can I set this value by default so I do not have to retype it everytime.

I work on a Windows 7 machine

Thank  you

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Set environment variables on Mac OS X Lion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7501678/set-environment-variables-on-mac-os-x-lion). It's bascially *nix stuff.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to fix the issue by adding TERM=xterm to my bash.bashrc file