# How do I install a script to path on Mac OS on VScode

Tags: python, bash, visual-studio-code, path, zsh

Every time I install something using pip I get this warning message and the package I installed doesn't work. I don't understand what path is or how to fix it. I keep seeing solutions saying to simply change the files to the absolute path but fail to elaborate on how to do so. Other solutions I see seemingly only apply to windows and I'm a Mac user.

`WARNING: The scripts pip, pip3 and pip3.8 are installed in '/Users/landonbragg/Library/Python/3.8/bin' which is not on PATH. Consider adding this directory to PATH or, if you prefer to suppress this warning, use --no-warn-script-location`

For example of my problem, I've installed pytest but whenever I try to run it I get the error message...

```
zsh: command not found: pytest
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try to add this directory to your path?:

`/Users/landonbragg/Library/Python/3.8/bin`

If not, maybe you want to check this post out [How to set PATH environment variable?](https://superuser.com/questions/562169/how-to-set-path-environment-variable)

Comment: Thank you so much, do you know if its possible to have newly created directories automatically be set to my path, and if so how can I do that?

Comment: You can find a way to set the path to your environmental variables with the command line but tbh, I have no idea if you can set the path automatically without any action.

Answer (score 0):

For the installation, try using this command `python3 -m pip install <Module>` instead of `pip install <Module>`

Answer (score 0):

> WARNING: The scripts pip, pip3 and pip3.8 are installed in '/Users/landonbragg/Library/Python/3.8/bin' which is not on PATH. Consider adding this directory to PATH

The warning tells you what to do. Add `'/Users/landonbragg/Library/Python/3.8/bin'` to [the environment variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7501678/set-environment-variables-on-mac-os-x-lion)