# Trouble running server for Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, terminal, server-error

I have been able to run the server for my rails app, until today when I entered 'rails s', it gave this error:

```
    Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "bcrypt-ruby":
  In snapshot (Gemfile.lock):
    bcrypt-ruby (3.1.5)

  In Gemfile:
    sorcery (>= 0) ruby depends on
      bcrypt-ruby (>= 3.0) ruby

Running `bundle update` will rebuild your snapshot from scratch, using only
the gems in your Gemfile, which may resolve the conflict.
```

I ran 'bundle update' and it gave me yet another error

```
 An error occurred while installing pg (0.17.1), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install pg -v '0.17.1'` succeeds before bundling.
```

I then decided to install rails through typing the following command

```
gem install rails --no-ri --no-rdoc
```

Everything ran smoothly, but once I ran 'rails --version' to verify, the terminal gave me this error:

```
    Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "bcrypt-ruby":
  In snapshot (Gemfile.lock):
    bcrypt-ruby (3.1.5)

  In Gemfile:
    sorcery (>= 0) ruby depends on
      bcrypt-ruby (>= 3.0) ruby

Running `bundle update` will rebuild your snapshot from scratch, using only
the gems in your Gemfile, which may resolve the conflict.
```

I don't understand what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Did you try installing the pg gem `gem install pg -v '0.17.1'` ?

Comment: Yes, I did. I got this error: Can't find the 'libpq-fe.h header
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Comment: If you're on debian/ubuntu try running `sudo apt-get install libpq-dev`, that solved it for me once.

Comment: If that doesn't do the trick there are some suggestions here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4827092/unable-to-install-pg-gem