# "rake db:migrate" results in "The bundle currently has pg locked at 0.18.4"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, pg, sqlite3-ruby

I generated this scaffold in Rails.  Then I did a "rake db:migrate".  Then I got:

```
[31mYou have requested:
pg >= 0
The bundle currently has pg locked at 0.18.4.
Try running `bundle update pg`[0m
[33mRun `bundle install` to install missing gems.[0m
```

Then I did "bundle update" and "bundle install" which resulted in:

Installing pg 0.18.4 with native extensions
C:/jruby-9.0.4.0/lib/ruby/stdlib/rubygems/ext/ext_conf_builder.rb:39: warning: Tempfile#unlink or delete called on open file; ignoring

```
Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

C:/jruby-9.0.4.0/bin/jruby.exe -r ./siteconf20151205-6108-1bkqm97.rb     >extconf.rb
NotImplementedError: C extensions are not supported
<top> at C:/jruby-9.0.4.0/lib/ruby/stdlib/mkmf.rb:1
require at org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:939
(root) at     C:/jruby>9.0.4.0/lib/ruby/stdlib/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:1
<top> at extconf.rb:2
extconf failed, exit code 1
Gem files will remain installed in C:/jruby-    9.0.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/pg-0.18.4 for inspection.
Results logged to C:/jruby-    9.0.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/shared/extensions/universal-java-1.8/2.2.0/pg-    0.18.4/gem_make.out
An error occurred while installing pg (0.18.4), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install pg -v '0.18.4'` succeeds before bundling.
```

In my Gemfile, I tried making "gem 'pg'" plain, then "bundle install"ing, but still got the error message.

Here's my Gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'  
group :production do  
gem 'rails_12factor'  
gem 'pg'  
end  
group :development, :test do  
gem 'sqlite3'  
end  
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.3'  
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'  
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.0.0'  
gem 'jquery-rails'  
gem 'turbolinks'  
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'  
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0',          group: :doc  
gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin]  
gem 'coffee-script-source', '1.8.0'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you're on a Windows machine running jRuby. Try using one of the following gems instead of pg:

https://github.com/jruby/activerecord-jdbc-adapter

https://github.com/headius/jruby-pg

This answer might also be of help:
[unable to install pg gem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4827092/unable-to-install-pg-gem)

Comment: Thanks!  You're right!  I'm on a Windows machine.  I think acriverecord-jdbc-adapter fixed the error that I got out of pg, but I'm getting a similar error now for sqlite3 when I bundle install.  I'll try to work on this.  Thanks, again!  :)

Comment: Cool. Not sure what's up with sqlite not installing, but you might check here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15480381/how-do-i-install-sqlite3-for-ruby-on-windows