# Problem with PostgreSQL and Ruby on Windows

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

When I try

> gem install pg

I get this error

> C:/Ruby192/bin/ruby.exe extconf.rb
>   checking for pg_config... yes
>   Using config values from C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.0\bin/pg_config.exe
>   *** extconf.rb failed ***
>   Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
>   necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
>   details.  You may need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --without-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=C:/Ruby192/bin/ruby
    --with-pg
    --without-pg
    --with-pg-dir
    --without-pg-dir
    --with-pg-include
    --without-pg-include=${pg-dir}/include
    --with-pg-lib
    --without-pg-lib=${pg-dir}/lib
    --with-pg-config
    --without-pg-config
    --with-pg_config
    --without-pg_config
extconf.rb:13:in `` `': No such file or directory - C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.0\bin/pg_config.exe --includedir (Errno::ENOENT)
    from extconf.rb:13:in ``'

Any advice?

Comment: You do have Postgres installed, right? Is it somewhere other than `C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.0`?

Comment: Yeah it's Installed and that is the exact directory...For now I've solved using the 0.9.0 version gem install pg -v=0.9.0 this installs without problems.

Answer (score 1):

I've already provided an answer to this problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4335750/cant-install-pg-gem-on-windows/4336003#4336003).