# Error when running rails s "require cannot load such file, rescue in <top (required)> & block in require"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database

I am using ruby 2.5.5p157, Rails 4.2.6, git bash 2.22.0, Bundler version 1.13.6 and windows 10 OS.
I am currently taking over a project done by another person to add some minor features in but discovered that the project is done in ruby which i have no background in. I have the whole completed project file and i need to setup a separate database server to add in a new feature to test it out but the project was done a few years back and i can't contact the person because i do not know who was the one to do it.
So here i am trying to just set up the database of the file after installing git bash, ruby and rails but run into this error after i have "bundle install" and run "rails s" in git bash.

I have tried uninstalling PG gem and installing again,update bundle & install bundle but these does not work. I have also tried updating PG but does not work either.

```
$ rails s
C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/pg-0.18.4-x64-mingw32/lib/pg.rb:14:in `require': cannot load such file -- 2.5/pg_ext (LoadError)
        from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/pg-0.18.4-x64-mingw32/lib/pg.rb:14:in `rescue in <top (required)>'
        from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/pg-0.18.4-x64-mingw32/lib/pg.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0/bundler/runtime.rb:81:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0/bundler/runtime.rb:81:in `block (2 levels) in require'
        from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `each'
        from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `block in require'
        from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0/bundler/runtime.rb:65:in `each'
        from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0/bundler/runtime.rb:65:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0/bundler.rb:114:in `require'
        from C:/sites/nyp-backend/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:78:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:78:in `block in server'
        from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `tap'
        from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `server'
        from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in `run_command!'
        from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
        from bin/rails:4:in `require'
        from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
```

Here's my jem list in case you need to know:

```
$ gem list
aasm (4.10.1, 4.10.0)
actioncable (5.2.3)
actionmailer (5.2.3, 4.2.6)
actionpack (5.2.3, 4.2.6)
actionview (5.2.3, 4.2.6)
activejob (5.2.3, 4.2.6)
activemodel (5.2.3, 4.2.6)
activerecord (5.2.3, 4.2.6)
activestorage (5.2.3)
activesupport (5.2.3, 4.2.6)
acts_as_commentable (4.0.2)
acts_as_list (0.7.4)
administrate (0.2.2)
akami (1.3.1)
arel (9.0.0, 6.0.4, 6.0.3)
autoprefixer-rails (6.7.7.2)
aws-sdk (1.67.0)
aws-sdk-v1 (1.67.0)
axiom-types (0.1.1)
bcrypt (3.1.13, 3.1.11 x64-mingw32)
better_errors (2.5.1)
bigdecimal (default: 1.3.4)
binding_of_caller (0.8.0)
bootstrap-datepicker-rails (1.6.0.1)
bootstrap-sass (3.3.7)
bootstrap3-datetimepicker-rails (4.17.47)
builder (3.2.3, 3.2.2)
bundle (0.0.1)
bundler (2.0.1, default: 1.17.3, 1.13.6)
byebug (11.0.1, 8.2.2)
cancancan (1.17.0, 1.13.1)
capistrano (3.4.1)
capistrano-bundler (1.5.0)
capistrano-faster-assets (1.1.0)
capistrano-passenger (0.2.0)
capistrano-rails (1.1.8)
capistrano-rvm (0.1.2)
chronic (0.10.2)
chunky_png (1.3.11, 1.3.5)
climate_control (0.2.0)
cmath (default: 1.0.0)
cocaine (0.5.8)
cocoon (1.2.9)
coderay (1.1.2, 1.1.1)
coercible (1.0.0)
coffee-rails (4.1.1)
coffee-script (2.4.1)
coffee-script-source (1.12.2, 1.10.0)
compass (1.0.3)
compass-core (1.0.3)
compass-import-once (1.0.5)
compass-rails (3.0.2)
concurrent-ruby (1.1.5, 1.0.1)
crass (1.0.4)
csv (default: 1.0.0)
daemons (1.2.6, 1.2.3)
database_cleaner (1.5.3, 1.5.1)
date (default: 1.0.0)
datetime_picker_rails (0.0.7)
dbm (default: 1.0.0)
debug_inspector (0.0.3, 0.0.2)
delayed_job (4.1.5)
delayed_job_active_record (4.1.3)
descendants_tracker (0.0.4)
devise (3.5.10)
did_you_mean (1.2.0)
diff-lcs (1.3, 1.2.5)
dotenv (2.1.2, 2.1.1)
dotenv-rails (2.1.2)
equalizer (0.0.11)
erubi (1.8.0)
erubis (2.7.0)
etc (default: 1.0.0)
exception_notification (4.1.1)
execjs (2.7.0, 2.6.0)
factory_girl (4.5.0)
factory_girl_rails (4.5.0)
faker (1.6.6, 1.6.3)
fcntl (default: 1.0.0)
ffi (1.11.1 x64-mingw32, 1.9.10 x64-mingw32)
fiddle (default: 1.0.0)
fileutils (default: 1.0.2)
formatador (0.2.5)
gdbm (default: 2.0.0)
globalid (0.4.2)
grape (0.15.0)
grape-entity (0.4.8)
grape-swagger (0.10.5)
grape-swagger-rails (0.2.2)
guard (2.15.0)
guard-compat (1.2.1)
guard-rspec (4.6.5)
gyoku (1.3.1)
hashie (3.6.0, 3.4.3)
hashie-forbidden_attributes (0.1.1)
httpi (2.4.4)
i18n (1.6.0, 0.9.5, 0.7.0)
ice_nine (0.11.2)
io-console (default: 0.4.6)
ipaddr (default: 1.2.0)
jbuilder (2.9.1)
jquery-rails (4.3.3)
json (default: 2.1.0, 1.8.6)
kaminari (0.16.3)
listen (3.1.5)
loofah (2.2.3)
lumberjack (1.0.13, 1.0.10)
mail (2.7.1)
marcel (0.3.3)
method_source (0.9.2, 0.8.2)
mime-types (3.2.2)
mime-types-data (3.2019.0331, 3.2016.0221)
mimemagic (0.3.3, 0.3.0)
mini_mime (1.0.1)
mini_portile2 (2.4.0, 2.0.0)
minitest (5.11.3, 5.10.3, 5.8.4)
momentjs-rails (2.20.1)
multi_json (1.13.1, 1.11.2)
multi_xml (0.6.0, 0.5.5)
neat (1.9.1)
nenv (0.3.0)
net-scp (2.0.0)
net-ssh (5.2.0, 3.1.1)
net-telnet (0.1.1)
nio4r (2.3.1)
nokogiri (1.10.3 x64-mingw32)
nori (2.6.0)
normalize-rails (3.0.3)
notiffany (0.1.1)
openssl (default: 2.1.2)
orm_adapter (0.5.0)
paperclip (4.3.7)
passenger (5.0.30)
pg (1.1.4 x64-mingw32, 0.18.4 x64-mingw32)
power_assert (1.1.1)
pry (0.12.2)
psych (default: 3.0.2)
rack (2.0.7, 1.6.11, 1.6.4)
rack-accept (0.4.5)
rack-mount (0.8.3)
rack-test (1.1.0, 0.6.3)
rails (5.2.3, 4.2.6)
rails-deprecated_sanitizer (1.0.3)
rails-dom-testing (2.0.3, 1.0.9)
rails-html-sanitizer (1.0.4)
railties (5.2.3, 4.2.6)
rake (12.3.2, 12.3.0, 11.1.2)
rb-fsevent (0.10.3, 0.9.7)
rb-inotify (0.10.0)
rdoc (default: 6.0.1, 4.3.0)
responders (2.4.1)
rqrcode (0.10.1)
rspec (3.4.0)
rspec-core (3.4.4)
rspec-expectations (3.4.0)
rspec-mocks (3.4.1)
rspec-rails (3.4.2)
rspec-support (3.4.1)
ruby_dep (1.5.0)
rubygems-update (3.0.3)
sass (3.4.25, 3.4.21)
sass-rails (5.0.7)
savon (2.11.2)
scanf (default: 1.0.0)
sdbm (default: 1.0.0)
sdoc (0.4.2)
select2-rails (4.0.1.1)
selectize-rails (0.12.6, 0.12.1)
shellany (0.0.1)
simple_form (3.2.1)
slim (3.0.9)
slop (3.6.0)
socialization (1.2.3)
socksify (1.7.1)
spring (2.0.2, 1.6.4)
spring-commands-rspec (1.0.4)
sprockets (3.7.2)
sprockets-rails (3.2.1)
sshkit (1.18.2)
stringio (default: 0.0.1)
strscan (default: 1.0.0)
temple (0.8.1, 0.7.6)
test-unit (3.2.7)
thor (0.20.3, 0.19.1)
thread_safe (0.3.6, 0.3.5)
tilt (2.0.9, 2.0.2)
timecop (0.8.1, 0.8.0)
turbolinks (5.2.0)
turbolinks-source (5.2.0)
tzinfo (1.2.5)
uglifier (4.1.20)
virtus (1.0.5)
warden (1.2.7)
wasabi (3.5.0)
web-console (2.3.0)
webrick (default: 1.4.2)
websocket-driver (0.7.0)
websocket-extensions (0.1.3)
whenever (0.11.0)
xmlrpc (0.3.0)
zlib (default: 1.0.0)
```

in case you need to know what is installed in the bundle and their version:

```
$ bundle install
Using rake 12.3.2
Using aasm 4.10.1
Using concurrent-ruby 1.1.5
Using i18n 0.9.5
Using json 1.8.6
Using minitest 5.11.3
Using thread_safe 0.3.6
Using tzinfo 1.2.5
Using activesupport 4.2.6
Using builder 3.2.3
Using erubis 2.7.0
Using mini_portile2 2.4.0
Using nokogiri 1.10.3 (x64-mingw32)
Using rails-deprecated_sanitizer 1.0.3
Using rails-dom-testing 1.0.9
Using crass 1.0.4
Using loofah 2.2.3
Using rails-html-sanitizer 1.0.4
Using actionview 4.2.6
Using rack 1.6.11
Using rack-test 0.6.3
Using actionpack 4.2.6
Using globalid 0.4.2
Using activejob 4.2.6
Using mini_mime 1.0.1
Using mail 2.7.1
Using actionmailer 4.2.6
Using activemodel 4.2.6
Using arel 6.0.4
Using activerecord 4.2.6
Using acts_as_commentable 4.0.2
Using acts_as_list 0.7.4
Using execjs 2.7.0
Using autoprefixer-rails 6.7.7.2
Using thor 0.20.3
Using railties 4.2.6
Using momentjs-rails 2.20.1
Using datetime_picker_rails 0.0.7
Using jquery-rails 4.3.3
Using kaminari 0.16.3
Using sass 3.4.25
Using neat 1.9.1
Using normalize-rails 3.0.3
Using bundler 1.17.3
Using sprockets 3.7.2
Using sprockets-rails 3.2.1
Using rails 4.2.6
Using tilt 2.0.9
Using sass-rails 5.0.7
Using selectize-rails 0.12.6
Using administrate 0.2.2
Using gyoku 1.3.1
Using akami 1.3.1
Using aws-sdk-v1 1.67.0
Using aws-sdk 1.67.0
Using descendants_tracker 0.0.4
Using ice_nine 0.11.2
Using axiom-types 0.1.1
Using bcrypt 3.1.13
Using coderay 1.1.2
Using erubi 1.8.0
Using better_errors 2.5.1
Using debug_inspector 0.0.3
Using binding_of_caller 0.8.0
Using bootstrap-datepicker-rails 1.6.0.1
Using bootstrap-sass 3.3.7
Using bootstrap3-datetimepicker-rails 4.17.47
Using byebug 11.0.1
Using cancancan 1.17.0
Using net-ssh 5.2.0
Using net-scp 2.0.0
Using sshkit 1.18.2
Using capistrano 3.4.1
Using capistrano-bundler 1.5.0
Using capistrano-faster-assets 1.1.0
Using capistrano-passenger 0.2.0
Using capistrano-rails 1.1.8
Using capistrano-rvm 0.1.2
Using chronic 0.10.2
Using chunky_png 1.3.11
Using climate_control 0.2.0
Using cocaine 0.5.8
Using cocoon 1.2.9
Using coercible 1.0.0
Using coffee-script-source 1.12.2
Using coffee-script 2.4.1
Using coffee-rails 4.1.1
Using multi_json 1.13.1
Using compass-core 1.0.3
Using compass-import-once 1.0.5
Using rb-fsevent 0.10.3
Using ffi 1.11.1 (x64-mingw32)
Using rb-inotify 0.10.0
Using compass 1.0.3
Using compass-rails 3.0.2
Using daemons 1.2.6
Using database_cleaner 1.5.3
Using delayed_job 4.1.5
Using delayed_job_active_record 4.1.3
Using orm_adapter 0.5.0
Using responders 2.4.1
Using warden 1.2.7
Using devise 3.5.10
Using diff-lcs 1.3
Using dotenv 2.1.2
Using dotenv-rails 2.1.2
Using equalizer 0.0.11
Using exception_notification 4.1.1
Using factory_girl 4.5.0
Using factory_girl_rails 4.5.0
Using faker 1.6.6
Using formatador 0.2.5
Using hashie 3.6.0
Using multi_xml 0.6.0
Using rack-accept 0.4.5
Using rack-mount 0.8.3
Using virtus 1.0.5
Using grape 0.15.0
Using grape-entity 0.4.8
Using grape-swagger 0.10.5
Using grape-swagger-rails 0.2.2
Using ruby_dep 1.5.0
Using listen 3.1.5
Using lumberjack 1.0.13
Using nenv 0.3.0
Using shellany 0.0.1
Using notiffany 0.1.1
Using method_source 0.9.2
Using pry 0.12.2
Using guard 2.15.0
Using guard-compat 1.2.1
Using rspec-support 3.4.1
Using rspec-core 3.4.4
Using rspec-expectations 3.4.0
Using rspec-mocks 3.4.1
Using rspec 3.4.0
Using guard-rspec 4.6.5
Using hashie-forbidden_attributes 0.1.1
Using socksify 1.7.1
Using httpi 2.4.4
Using jbuilder 2.9.1
Using mime-types-data 3.2019.0331
Using mime-types 3.2.2
Using mimemagic 0.3.0
Using nori 2.6.0
Using paperclip 4.3.7
Using passenger 5.0.30
Using pg 0.18.4 (x64-mingw32)
Using rdoc 4.3.0
Using rqrcode 0.10.1
Using rspec-rails 3.4.2
Using wasabi 3.5.0
Using savon 2.11.2
Using sdoc 0.4.2
Using select2-rails 4.0.1.1
Using simple_form 3.2.1
Using temple 0.8.1
Using slim 3.0.9
Using socialization 1.2.3
Using spring 2.0.2
Using spring-commands-rspec 1.0.4
Using timecop 0.8.1
Using turbolinks-source 5.2.0
Using turbolinks 5.2.0
Using uglifier 4.1.20
Using web-console 2.3.0
Using whenever 0.11.0
Bundle complete! 57 Gemfile dependencies, 167 gems now installed.
Use `bundle info [gemname]` to see where a bundled gem is installed.
```

It would be great if anyone can help guide me with the setting up of a server database for ruby. Thanks!

Comment: Are you using the windows subsystem for linux? or rails installer for your ruby/rails installation?

Comment: @JayDorsey I'm just using windows. For rails, i used rails installer (ruby 2.2).

Answer (score 1):

`pg` gem requires few packages to be installed with it.

You didn't specify your system so here are few examples:

**Debian/Ubuntu**
`sudo apt-get install libpq-dev`

**Mac**
It comes with postgresql `brew install postgresql`

**Windows**
I will point to a different SO thread: [Can't install pg gem on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4335750/cant-install-pg-gem-on-windows)

Comment: Hi Michael, i am using windows OS.

Comment: @Rei hey, i edited it for Windows. Try to look there :) Good luck!